# Saving data in coredata?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, core-data

I am below code to save data in coredata database.Please tell me what is the better way of doing it.

```
func saveToDB() {
    if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        Info =  NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Sinfo", into: appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext) as! Sinfo
    } else {
        Info = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Sinfo", into: appDelegate.managedObjectContext!) as! Sinfo
    }
    info?.title = Comman.shared.title
    info?.desc = Comman.shared.desc
    info?.id = String(Utility.shared.currentTimeStamp())
    info?.cordinates = Comman.shared.cordinates?.joined(separator: ",")
    let ocation  = Comman.shared.location
    info?.city = location?.city
    info?.state = location?.state
    info?.country = location?.country
    info?.state = location?.state
    info?.zip = location?.pincode
    info?.isuploaded = false
    appDelegate.saveContext()
}
```

Comment: This would be a better fit at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: At least a better way is to use much less question marks ;-) and Swift is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

you can use like

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

let newcontact = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Employee", into: context) as NSManagedObject
        
newcontact.setValue(txtempid.text, forKey: "emp_id")
newcontact.setValue(txtempname.text, forKey: "emp_name")
newcontact.setValue(txtempadd.text, forKey: "emp_add")
        
do {
   try   context.save()
} catch {
}
```

Comment: Can i use NSManaged subclass for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to use a persistentContainer is you are not ios 10 and above only.  Just create a stack that works and use it.  PersistentContainer helps in not having to create a core data stack, but if you are creating one anyway there is really no point to using it.